# How to download and remove e-mails from IMAP Gmail?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, gmail, archiving, gmail-imap

How is Gmail [exported](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10016932?hl=en) so that it's [removed](https://superuser.com/q/1707012/977796) from Gmail?

Downloading the archive is one aspect, but that's a safe and non-destructive operation.  Looking to make it a destructive.

Something not far from "pop" the e-mail for local storage, in that it's removed from the server.  This is with IMAP, of course.

(At well above 90% of storage.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Something not far from "pop" the e-mail for local storage, in that it's removed from the server. This is with IMAP, of course.

The only thing that actually makes POP destructive is the clients' use of the `DELE` command to delete each message that was just retrieved. So you can do it via IMAP using exactly the same operations as in POP:

0. Get a list of messages.
1. Retrieve a message.
2. Delete the message.
3. GOTO 1

If this is a one-time job, probably any desktop IMAP client (such as Thunderbird) will allow you to a) drag and drop all messages into a local folder or into another server, or just b) select all messages and delete them.

For periodic one-way sync, `fetchmail` supports the same "fetch and delete" process with IMAP as it does with POP. Getmail probably does as well.

Comment: thanks, trying fetchmail as https://askubuntu.com/q/1497114/847449